# 'script' command in terminal, looking for a flush open

Tags: terminal, script

When I use 'script' on a unix terminal the -f option flushes the data straight to the file - from the man page "-f      Flush output after each write. This is nice for telecooperation: One person does `mkfifo foo; script -f foo' and another can
             supervise real-time what is being done using`cat foo'."

This is a really handy option for me - but the version of the script command on my mac appears to be lacking this option. Are there any ways I can achieve the functionality?

Comment: Can't you achive the same result with `script -t 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve more or less the same result by running

```
script -t 0
```

From the man page:

```
-t time  Specify time interval between flushing script output file.
         A value of 0 causes script to flush for every
         character I/O event.  The default interval is 30 seconds.
```